# What are the advantages and disadvantages of having internal memory in ALU ?

Tags: computer-science, cpu-architecture

In ALU, when two 32 bits input is given then 64 bits output is received. How ALU's stores and processes data to produce the output?
Does ALU have some internal storage? If yes, what are the advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: The question isn't clear - what ALU? which operation are you asking about? why do you think it requires storage?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, something like an ALU would have a [latch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(electronics)) to keep the input data on the internal wiring / data paths until the next clock cycle.  There are latches between every pipeline stage which accept new data on every clock cycle (assuming fully-pipelined ALUs, e.g. one-per-clock throughput with multi-cycle latency.)  So the data isn't stored in any kind of "memory", other than the latches between pipeline stages.  Mostly it's just live in the logic gates.